# Cannot import keras optimizers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have installed tensortflow and keras on my windows 10 but some thinks does not work.
For example, it shows these errors:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import to_categorical

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import to_categorical
ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

Also, at this line it shows this error:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD

from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD
ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py)
```

I have also tried with other optimizers such as Adam/adam but the result is the same.
Versions:

```
Python 3.8

Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.4.1

Name: Keras
Version: 2.4.3
```

Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Possibly a dependency conflict? Try reinstalling Keras and see if that helps.

Comment: if you do from tensorflow..keras.optimizers import SGD what message you get?

Comment: the same that I wrote

Comment: Is this the complete error messages? If not please include the whole traceback in your question

Comment: Could you go to the library installed location and check if anything is missing? If so, try to reinstall tensorflow.

Comment: Anything under `tf.python.*` is private. It is intended for development rather than public use. Generally it not recommend to use, instead can you try as `from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical;
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD`. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thats the whole message

Comment: Can you try `import tensorflow as tf; tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()` ? Is this actually windows 10 by the way? The path looks like a macOS path.